# how to view image by using server side processing datatables in view table

Tags: php

how to view image by using server side processing data tables in view table

```
$subdata[]='<img src="<?php $row[11] ;?>" height="100" width="100"/> <?php =$row[11] ;?></img>';

$data=array(); 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
$subdata=array(); 
$subdata[]=$row[0]; 
$subdata[]=$row[1];//name 
$subdata[]=$row[2];//email 
$subdata[]=$row[3];//pass 
$subdata[]=$row[4];//cpass 
$subdata[]=$row[5];//lang 
$subdata[]=$row[6];//rol 
$subdata[]=$row[7];//sal 
$subdata[]=$row[8];//gen 
$subdata[]=$row[9];//num 
$subdata[]=$row[10];//add 
$subdata[]=$row[11];//photo 
$subdata[]='<img src="<?php $row[11] ;?>" height="100" width="100"/> <?php =$row[11] ;?></img>';
```

Comment: $data=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
 $subdata=array();
 $subdata[]=$row[0];
 $subdata[]=$row[1];//name
 $subdata[]=$row[2];//email
 $subdata[]=$row[3];//pass
 $subdata[]=$row[4];//cpass
 $subdata[]=$row[5];//lang
 $subdata[]=$row[6];//rol
 $subdata[]=$row[7];//sal
 $subdata[]=$row[8];//gen
 $subdata[]=$row[9];//num
 $subdata[]=$row[10];//add
 //$subdata[]=$row[11];//photo                   
  $subdata[]='<img src="<?php $row[11] ;?>" height="100" width="100"/> <?php =$row[11] ;?></img>';

Comment: please explain better your problem

Comment: Can you explain a little more what exactly your problem is? What doesn't work? And please don't paste code in the comments, instead Edit your question and paste all relevant code/information there. Thanks

Comment: You are missing the "=" in the first <?php $row[11] if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is use the image file name saved on the db to fetch the picture from the folder it is saved to.

Let say, while trying to save the picture, which would probably have taken place when a form is being fill, is save to a folder called

> image folder

and assuming the image folder is in the same directory you are working from e.g. You are working in the public folder and inside the public folder, you also have the image folder, then you can do something like this.

```
'<img src="/img/<?php echo $row[11] ;?>" height="100" width="100"/>;
```

but if it is 2 folders inside the working directory i.e the

> image folder

is inside another directory or folder in the same public folder, what you have to do is include the folder name as well(the name of the folder will come first before the name of where the image reside). Assuming the name of the folder containing the image name is car, you can do this.

```
'<img src="/car/img/<?php echo $row[11] ;?>" height="100" width="100"/>;
```

but what if it is outside the working directory, i.e, you are working outside the public folder which I have been using as an example, then, we the dot operator to go back

> .. 
>   to go back, so you could do something like this

```
'<img src="/../img/<?php echo $row[11] ;?>" height="100" width="100"/>;
```

Assuming the image folder is created outside the public folder